# How to automatically share posts on facebook?

Tags: posts, facebook

Basically, I would like to know how to make a post appear on facebook (like when you press a facebook share button.) the right instant you click 'Publish'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several plugins you can use. One of such plugin is Wordbook.